# How can I disable the security warning when viewing XML in IE?

Tags: xml, security, internet-explorer

When I view XML files in Internet Explorer, it does syntax highlighting and provides clickable expand/collapse controls. But for every file I open, I get a yellow 
warning bar that takes three clicks to dismiss. These are local files, so the security warning shouldn't be necessary. Can it be disabled?

[IE yellow security warning bar for viewing local xml file http://carrieandtim.com/drop/iexmlwarning.png](http://carrieandtim.com/drop/iexmlwarning.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The previous suggestions on this page didn't work for me. I found the answer on [this page](http://www.leonmeijer.nl/archive/2008/04/27/106.aspx)

To summarise, go into Internet Options > Advanced then down to the Security section, and tick the box for "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer*"

The * means the setting only takes effect after Internet Explorer is restarted.

Comment: Thanks! That's the setting I was looking for.

Comment: I was desperately looking this. IE made me crazy with this paranoic security setting when clicking on *my* xml and xsl.Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the Windows help (if you click "More Information" from the Information Bar context menu):

> To stop the information bar from blocking file and software downloads
>
> - Click to open Internet Explorer.
> - Click the Tools button, and then    click Internet Options.
> - Click the Security tab, and then    click Custom level.
> - Do one or both of the following:
>
>   - To turn off the Information bar for ActiveX controls, scroll to the ActiveX controls and plug-ins section of the list, and then, under Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls, click Enable.
>   - To turn off the Information bar for file downloads, scroll to the Downloads section of the list, and then, under Automatic prompting for file downloads, click Enable.
> - Click OK, click Yes to confirm that you want to make the change, and then click OK again

The XML viewer (that colors and adds expand/collapse) is an ActiveX control included with IE.  Note that disabling the security warning for this control will disable all warnings for ActiveX controls which may not be a good thing.  It sounds like you'll still get a warning for first time use of a control (see the additional "Allow previously unused ActiveX controls to run without prompt" option), but I can't confirm that.

Comment: I don't want to disable the yellow security bar *globally* - I just want to disable it when viewing local XML files. IE itself is injecting the (useful) javascript for the element expand/collapse button. It's safe.

Comment: Do the same thing as what boyhowdy suggested, but select "Local Intranet" before tweaking anything.